# Pass variables to forms whilst loading them from tree views

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to load form by clicking tree view nodes. The below code is working, but now I need to pass some variables to the loading forms. So is there a way to pass variables when loading forms from a tree view.

```
string item = Convert.ToString(treeView1.SelectedNode);
        int index = item.IndexOf(" ");
        if (index > 0)
            item = item.Substring(index + 1);
        //MessageBox.Show(item);
        var selectedFRM = from Menu in dbdata.Menus
                          where Menu.Item_Name == item
                          select Menu;
        foreach (var pick in selectedFRM.Take(1))
        {
            string sel = pick.Form_Name;
            //Assembly asm = typeof(frmUser).Assembly;
            Assembly asm = typeof(frmCustomer).Assembly;
            Type type = asm.GetType("WindowsFormsApplication6." + sel);

            AssemblyName assemName = asm.GetName();
           // MessageBox.Show(assemName.Name);
            try
            {
                Form frmChk = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                //frmChk cgh = new frmChk();
                frmChk.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in loading form");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make public properties, variables, or methods in the form containing the treeview. The loading forms `frmChk` can access these in their load event (or anywhere else).